# Dustjs Display Unique Values Only?

Tags: dust.js

Lets say i have the following JSON

```
{
   names: ["John", "Peter", "Ron", "John", "James", "John"]
}
```

I need DustJS to render the following names

```
John 
Peter
Ron
James
```

Notice that these are unique values in an array. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: honestly I would just run an Array unique on the `context` and wrap it  in a new object. That way you have a unique array of names.  I wouldn't bother trying to use a dust filter.

Comment: Can you show some sample code please? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, though in looking at this, you should first start by changing your json:  `{names:[{"name":"John"},{"name":"Peter"},{"name":"Ron"}]}`

Comment: Hmmm is there any way to do this without modifying the JSON. Sounds like we need to request and update to Dust!

Comment: I'm sorry, your current object will work using `{#names}{.} {/names}`, you just need to unique the array.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a common algorithm to 'unique' an array:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
```

It's done by taking the values, attempting to add them as keys to an object (which will only work if they're different). If success, it adds that key to an array. If fail, it ignores the key. It then returns the array.  I have a working dust.js demo here:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UP7a4/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will generate your "also acceptable" form:

```
{#options}] {.} {#variants} {.options[$idx]} {/variants} {/options}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I posted questions for DustJS on StackOverflow, this answers the other question.

Comment: Is it possible to reference the {#options}{.}{/options} value inside {#variants}{/variants}? I tried passing it as a variable {#variants variable="{.}"}, but it returned [object][object].