# DustJS Nested Sections?

Tags: dust.js

Brownie points if you can provide some sort of feedback in this issue. Here's the JSON data

```
{
"options": [
    "Size",
    "Color"
  ],
  "variants": [
    {
      "inventory": 4,
      "options": [
        "S",
        "Red, White, Blue"
      ]
    },
    {
      "inventory": 4,
      "options": [
        "M",
        "Red, White, Blue"
      ]
    },
    {
      "inventory": 0,
      "options": [
        "L",
        "Red, White, Blue"
      ]
    },      
  ]
```

}

Here's the desire output

```
Size
S
M
L

Color
Red, White, Blue
```

This is also acceptable.

```
Size
S
M
L

Color
Red, White, Blue
Red, White, Blue
Red, White, Blue
```

I understand that I need to essentially nest the sections and match the option indexes, but not sure if it's possible with Dust JS.

```
{#options}
   {#variants}
      {.options}
          // If this option id matches the parent option id, then display it
      {/options}
   {/variants}
{/options}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by @rragan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566589/dustjs-display-unique-values-only). Here's the solution for reference:

```
{#options}
  {.}{~n}
  {#variants}
    {.options[$idx]}{~n}
  {/variants}{~n}
{/options}
```

Will generate

```
Size
S
M
L

Color
Red, White, Blue
Red, White, Blue
Red, White, Blue
```

Comment: You can reference current outer option by passing it in as a param to inner section. `{#options}{.}{#variants outerOp=.}{outerOp}{/variants}{/options}`